# How do you partially update a Meteor session var?

Tags: meteor

There's only `Session.set()` which sets the entire value for the session var.

Say that you've got an object:

```
Session.set('myObj', {
  fname: 'Bob',
  lname: 'Smith'
});
```

Is there a way to only set the value for `lname` while leaving `fname` untouched?

Would this be the most direct way?

```
Session.set('myObj', {
  fname: 'Bob',
  lname: 'Smith'
});

var tempObj = Session.get('myObj');
tempObj.lname = 'Lee';
Session.set('myObj', tempObj);
```

Comment: @fuzzynanybunny there is only set and get so it's either replace all or nothing if you want to change just something your proposed way is fine.  Or you can use multiple `reactive vars` to handle it sepreatly if it makes sense

Comment: @fuzzybabybunny Why not use a ReactiveDict instead?

Comment: @DavidWeldon, I'd like to keep all the info together as an object. It's an order form that stores all the things ordered, the customer info, the total price, etc. Changes in the customer info or items ordered have reactive changes in the view and automatic re-calculation of totals and such.